# Libgdx changing cellsizes without having the table rescaling everything

Tags: java, libgdx, cell

I am using a table with buttons, scrollpanes and textfields. But the problem is, when I change the size of a cell in the table..The entire table rescales. How do I change the size of a cell in a table without everything else with it?

I hope I expressed myself correctly in this.

Comment: Have you tried to define sizes to all cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this: [TableLayout documentation](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout).
It seems like `expand()` is more or less what you are looking for. It gives the selected cell the rest of the available space. also setting `width(desiredWidth)` and `height(desiredHeight)` should do what you like to do. You have to call this functions for the `Cell` you want to change. So store your cell like: `Cell cell = table.add(button);` and then use `cell.width(myWidth)` or directly use `table.add(button).width(myWidth);`. I think this should work. Note that this code is only pseudocode and you should not use this, but this concept.

Comment: I shall try playing around using the documentation. This seems to require quite a bit of tweaking but still. Its appreciated.

Comment: So this works for you? I never used TableLayout myself, but i have read a lot of things cause i wanted to use it. But it seems like i am to lazy to realy use it :(

Comment: It "sort of works". You still have to use pad and spacing like a madman it seems. Lots of debugging to see how things change and such :P

Comment: Ah okay. I don't know any better solution, but maybe someone else does. I wish you good luck :P